# WCF binding not being read

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

I am using a basic http binding and have set `maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"` on both the client and the service. My service is throwing an error however, with this message:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

I know it's using my binding because that's the only one I've enabled and other method calls work fine. Is this just a generic message and my object is really bigger than 2147483647 not 65536?

The binding looks like this on both the client and server

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Please post the entire config - it's possible that you're hitting the issue where there is a name mismatch between the `<service>` name attribute and the actual service name.

Comment: the contract name was misspelled. kinda weird how most methods worked though. if you post an answer i will accept it.

Comment: That's a really annoying thing about WCF. If a name fails to bind the framework SHOULD just throw an exception right away. Instead we have to spend hours debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a name mismatch in the config between the name attribute of the `<service>` element and the actual service name. The name must be the *fully-qualified name* of the service class.